# How to read PDF without using 3rd party dll in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am trying to read a PDF without using any third party dll.

I searched in Google but didn't find a good link to proceed.

In some links I found that: we can't read the content of PDF because its in binary format.

Is there any way to read PDF without third party dll or we have to use third party dll to read a PDF?

Comment: No, there is not. As you already stated, PDF is not a standard Microsoft format, so there's no possibility.
But you can code your own library.

Comment: You should also be weary of certain third party libraries being able to read particular versions of Adobe. I remember I had this problem as certain customers don't like upgrading software for whatever reason.

Comment: Can you please suggest some 3rd party free dll????

Comment: and if possible can you please share some code for integrate

Comment: Do you want your users to be able to download and view the file, or do you want to "read" the file in your code behind?

Comment: read the file in code behind

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use 3rd party solution
I recommend [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/)

Comment: is it free or paid one ??

Comment: Quote: "PDFsharp is the Open Source .NET library that easily creates and processes PDF documents on the fly from any .NET language."

Comment: You just have to include it as a project into your solution. It gives you a lot of options and it's highly custumizable

Comment: you're welcome :)
but here's similar question and same answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151708/c-sharp-code-for-converting-into-pdf-wothout-using-third-party-library?rq=1) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try it ,

```
byte[] yourByteData = .. assign your pdf data here ....
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/pdf");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length",yourByteData.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=sample.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(yourByteData);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: That doesn't open the PDF for reading, that serves it as a download.

Comment: Of course it is , have to install some web pdf viewer such as `Adobe PDF` ! this code is perfectly work for me BTW !

Comment: Let's ask the OP what he wants.

Comment: I want to read the PDF from code behind

Comment: one query

use of above code????

Comment: use of above code,if i serve byte array what it will do 

will it generate a pdf or what??

Comment: If you have pdf in your database as `varbinary` , get this value and just bind as `byte[]` datatype in some event (eg. Button_click) and use this code !